# Installed Obsidian in Ubuntu with Snap, Creates Symlinks on First Run and Fails

Tags: obsidian

I recently installed [obsidian](https://obsidian.md) in WSL ubuntu using snap `sudo snap install obsidian --classic`. But, when I first run `obsidian`, it creates recursive symlinks in my user directory and then fails because of those symlinks on later calls. I've deleted the symlinks and ran again but `obsidian` will still fail with no error message, status code 1. What is going on, and how do I resolve this issue? I could point these symlinks to the respective windows folders, but I don't want to try anything custom until I know what's going on.

What `obsidian` does on first run:
[image]

The symlinks in my user directory:
[image]

Then, here is what happens when I delete those links.

```
~ anthony : rm -rf Desktop Documents Downloads Music Pictures Public Templates Videos
~ anthony : obsidian
~ anthony : sudo snap remove obsidian
obsidian removed
~ anthony : sudo snap install obsidian --classic
obsidian 1.4.16 from Obsidian (obsidianmd) installed
~ anthony : obsidian
2023-11-27 19:16:54 Loading main app package /snap/obsidian/21/resources/obsidian.asar
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/anthony/snap/obsidian/21/.config/obsidian/obsidian.json'
    at Object.openSync (node:fs:601:3)
    at Object.func [as openSync] (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:2:1869)
    at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:469:35)
    at t.readFileSync (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:2:9212)
    at /snap/obsidian/21/resources/obsidian.asar/main.js:1:3390
    at R (/snap/obsidian/21/resources/obsidian.asar/main.js:1:2117)
    at E (/snap/obsidian/21/resources/obsidian.asar/main.js:1:3371)
    at module.exports (/snap/obsidian/21/resources/obsidian.asar/main.js:6:3411)
    at loadApp (/snap/obsidian/21/resources/app.asar/main.js:294:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/snap/obsidian/21/resources/app.asar/main.js:446:12) {
  errno: -2,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: '/home/anthony/snap/obsidian/21/.config/obsidian/obsidian.json'
}
LaunchProcess: failed to execvp:
xdg-settings
2023-11-27 19:16:54 Checking for update using Github
2023-11-27 19:16:55 Success.
2023-11-27 19:16:55 Latest version is 1.4.16
2023-11-27 19:16:55 App is up to date.
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/anthony/snap/obsidian/21/.config/obsidian/b3bee8c2c6955f53.json'
    at Object.openSync (node:fs:601:3)
    at Object.func [as openSync] (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:2:1869)
    at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:469:35)
    at t.readFileSync (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:2:9212)
    at /snap/obsidian/21/resources/obsidian.asar/main.js:1:3390
    at R (/snap/obsidian/21/resources/obsidian.asar/main.js:1:2117)
    at E (/snap/obsidian/21/resources/obsidian.asar/main.js:1:3371)
    at N (/snap/obsidian/21/resources/obsidian.asar/main.js:25:1074)
    at s (/snap/obsidian/21/resources/obsidian.asar/main.js:25:10531)
    at IpcMainImpl.<anonymous> (/snap/obsidian/21/resources/obsidian.asar/main.js:25:6510) {
  errno: -2,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: '/home/anthony/snap/obsidian/21/.config/obsidian/b3bee8c2c6955f53.json'
}
~ anthony : obsidian
/home/anthony/Desktop was removed, reassigning DESKTOP to homedir
/home/anthony/Downloads was removed, reassigning DOWNLOAD to homedir
/home/anthony/Templates was removed, reassigning TEMPLATES to homedir
/home/anthony/Public was removed, reassigning PUBLICSHARE to homedir
/home/anthony/Documents was removed, reassigning DOCUMENTS to homedir
/home/anthony/Music was removed, reassigning MUSIC to homedir
/home/anthony/Pictures was removed, reassigning PICTURES to homedir
/home/anthony/Videos was removed, reassigning VIDEOS to homedir
~ anthony : obsidian
~ anthony :
```

Note the `obsidian` calls with no response throw status code 1.

Comment: Why are you installing obsidian in WSL ubuntu? You can download obsidian for Windows here: https://github.com/obsidianmd/obsidian-releases/releases/download/v1.4.16/Obsidian.1.4.16.exe

Comment: @HåkonHægland it's somewhat of an experiment, no practical need. But the problem is, from an outsider, very odd. The lack of an error message doesn't help

Comment: @HåkonHægland coming back to this, I do all of my git management in WSL, and I'd like to make a git repo for my obsidian vault. Not copying my configuration to windows is a plus